# Return 0, when SUM() has no records AND return SUM() with records

Tags: sql

I have the following tables filled with data:

Table: participants

```
+---------+--------+--------+
| eventID | person | guests |
+---------+--------+--------+
| 22      | John   | 10     |
| 22      | Pete   | 5      |
| 30      | Ian    | 3      |
+---------------------------+
```

Table: wp_posts

```
+----+------------+-----------+
| ID | post_title | post_type |
+----+------------+-----------+
| 22 | Christmas  | events    |
| 30 | New Year   | events    |
| 34 | Birthday   | events    |
| 38 | Easter     | events    |
| 39 | Ruhetag    | events    |
| 40 | St Patrick | events    |
+----+------------+-----------+
```

I am trying to write a query which returns a sum of guests who are registered for one of these events. But if no one is registered for the event, 0 should be returned.

This is the query I tried:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(p.guests), 0)
FROM participants p
JOIN wp_posts w ON p.eventID = w.ID
WHERE w.ID IN(22, 30, 34, 38, 39, 40)
GROUP BY w.ID
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------+
| COALESCE(SUM(p.quests), 0) |
+----------------------------+
| 15                         |
| 3                          |
+----------------------------+
```

Desired output:

```
+----------------------------+
| COALESCE(SUM(p.quests), 0) |
+----------------------------+
| 15                         |
| 3                          |
| 0                          |
| 0                          |
| 0                          |
| 0                          |
+----------------------------+
```

I realised that `COALESCE()` cannot return a 0, because there are no NULL records in the `participants` table.

Comment: What RDMS are you using? (Please tag it).

Comment: I am unsure what RDMS means.. I am assuming you mean what relationship the tables have to one another. The answer is none

Comment: Google? Relational database management system e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT participants.eventID
    , COALESCE(SUM(participants.guests), 0) AS "total_guests"
    , wp_posts.post_title
FROM participants
RIGHT JOIN wp_posts ON participants.eventID = wp_posts.ID
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = "events"
AND wp_posts.ID IN (22, 30, 34, 38, 39, 40)
GROUP BY wp_posts.post_title
```

Answer (score 1):

Select `FROM` the primary table, which in this case is the table you want to see all the results from e.g. `wp_posts` and `LEFT JOIN` on the sparse table e.g. `participants`.

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(p.guests),0) AS SumGuests
FROM wp_posts w
LEFT JOIN participants p ON p.eventID = w.ID
WHERE w.ID IN (22, 30, 34, 38, 39, 40)
GROUP BY w.ID;
```

Returns as desired

| SumGuests |
| --- |
| 15 |
| 3 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 0 |

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vvM_kPfs)

Comment: This returns the same result as my original statement and it also doesn't return 0 for the event, where no one has registered yet.

Comment: @cranked_coder fiddle added showing it works

Comment: As per result on my XAMPP MySQL, I can definitely say that this unfortunately isn't delivering the expected result. I tried with your solution and it didn't deliver '0's. Right Join on the other hand, for some reason did. And I didn't come up with this solution myself either.. it was a friend of mine and neither he could understand the outcome of right and left join. The query is executed on MySQL in wordpress data base.. so idk..

Comment: @cranked_coder Oh that's just because I forgot the coalesce, which I have added now. Also maybe now you can see why it's important to add details of your RDBMS (e.g. MySQL) to your question from the start

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using SQL Server.

```
select 
    b.Id , 
    coalesce(a.total_guests , 0) as total_guests 
from
(
    select 
        eventId , 
        sum(guests) as total_guests 
    from participants 
    group by eventId
    ) as a 
    right join wp_posts as b 
    on a.eventId = b.Id and b.post_type = 'events'
order by coalesce(a.total_guests , 0) desc;
```

Comment: Interesting....

Comment: This should work for any number of inputs.

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation in addition to a solution.